# CCIP Transfer not working for me on testnet (Sepolia-Mumbai)

Tags: chainlink

I'm making a tx with my ProgramableTransfer smart contracts for sending a message and sending ERC20 from Mumbai to Sepolia, I have deployed this contract that is receiver and sender at the same time in both blockchains, also I've allowed destination and source chain for mumbai in sepolia and for sepolia in mumbai, also allowing the address of each contract in the other chain. At the moment of making a sendMessagePayNative tx, it fails even when I have CCIP-BnM tokens for it.

The error and params are these:

[Params and error y mumbai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTCkI.png)

Idk why the EVM throws this error, my address is 0xc2B8Abc5249397DB5d159b4E3c311c2fAf4091f2 and my contracts are:

Mumbai: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x0738a659dce9b7a48e36a1f9d10a54deaf9f359c#writeContract

Sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x7f748eacdba684a4277af89894e1d6280196e2ec#writeContract

CCIP-BnM Mumbai: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xf1E3A5842EeEF51F2967b3F05D45DD4f4205FF40

CCIP-BnM Sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xFd57b4ddBf88a4e07fF4e34C487b99af2Fe82a05

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a token AND a message to an EOA (your wallet), but an EOA can only receive tokens, not messages